# Shared preferences for Color picker

Tags: android

I have the code for color picker but only picks the background color for the 1st activity when i move to next activity it does not work.

Splashactivity

```
public class Splash extends Activity { 
        private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT =3000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            /*
             * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
             * want to show case your app logo / company
             */

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                // Start your app main activity
                Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this,Themeactivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // close this activity
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }

    }
```

When i pass intent from splash to theme activity instead of main activity it does not work. since i need my theme activity after splash screen what should i do.

ThemeActivity

```
    public class ThemeActivity extends Activity implements ColorPicker.OnColorChangedListener {  
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */  
    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_theme);  
    this.activity = this;  
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    }

     public void onClick(View v) {
       switch (v.getId()) {

       case R.id.button2:
           Intent g = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
           startActivity(g);


        break; 
     }   
     }

     public void colorChanged(String str,int color) {    
     ThemeActivity.this.findViewById(android.R.id.content)  
    .setBackgroundColor(color);  
     }  

    Activity activity;  

    public void getColor(View v) {  
    new ColorPicker(activity, this, "", Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE).show();   
    }  
   }
```

Colorpicker.java

```
public class ColorPicker extends Dialog {  

public interface OnColorChangedListener {  
void colorChanged(String key, int color);  
}  

private OnColorChangedListener mListener;  
private int mInitialColor, mDefaultColor;  
private String mKey;  

private static class ColorPickerView extends View {  
private Paint mPaint;  
private float mCurrentHue = 0;  
private int mCurrentX = 0, mCurrentY = 0;  
private int mCurrentColor, mDefaultColor;  
private final int[] mHueBarColors = new int[258];  
private int[] mMainColors = new int[65536];  
private OnColorChangedListener mListener;  

 ColorPickerView(Context c, OnColorChangedListener l, int color, int defaultColor) {  
 super(c);  
 mListener = l;  
 mDefaultColor = defaultColor;  

 // Get the current hue from the current color and update the main  
 // color field  
 float[] hsv = new float[3];  
 Color.colorToHSV(color, hsv);  
 mCurrentHue = hsv[0];  
 updateMainColors();  

 mCurrentColor = color;  

 // Initialize the colors of the hue slider bar  
 int index = 0;  
 for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) // Red (#f00) to pink  
          // (#f0f)  
 {  
  mHueBarColors[index] = Color.rgb(255, 0, (int) i);  
  index++;  
  }  
 for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) // Pink (#f0f) to blue  
          // (#00f)  
 {  
  mHueBarColors[index] = Color.rgb(255 - (int) i, 0, 255);  
  index++;  
  }  
 for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) // Blue (#00f) to light  
          // blue (#0ff)  
 {  
  mHueBarColors[index] = Color.rgb(0, (int) i, 255);  
  index++;  
  }  
  for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) // Light blue (#0ff) to  
          // green (#0f0)  
 {  
  mHueBarColors[index] = Color.rgb(0, 255, 255 - (int) i);  
  index++;  
 }  
  for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) // Green (#0f0) to yellow  
          // (#ff0)  
  {  
  mHueBarColors[index] = Color.rgb((int) i, 255, 0);  
  index++;  
  }  
  for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) // Yellow (#ff0) to red  
          // (#f00)  
 {  
  mHueBarColors[index] = Color.rgb(255, 255 - (int) i, 0);  
  index++;  
  }  

  // Initializes the Paint that will draw the View  
  mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);  
  mPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);  
  mPaint.setTextSize(12);  
   }  

 // Get the current selected color from the hue bar  
  private int getCurrentMainColor() {  
  int translatedHue = 255 - (int) (mCurrentHue * 255 / 360);  
  int index = 0;  
  for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) {  
  if (index == translatedHue)  
  return Color.rgb(255, 0, (int) i);  
  index++;  
  }  
 for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) {  
 if (index == translatedHue)  
 return Color.rgb(255 - (int) i, 0, 255);  
 index++;  
}  
for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) {  
if (index == translatedHue)  
 return Color.rgb(0, (int) i, 255);  
 index++;  
 }  
 for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) {  
 if (index == translatedHue)  
 return Color.rgb(0, 255, 255 - (int) i);  
  index++;  
 }  
 for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) {  
  if (index == translatedHue)  
   return Color.rgb((int) i, 255, 0);  
  index++;  
 }   
 for (float i = 0; i < 256; i += 256 / 42) {  
  if (index == translatedHue)  
   return Color.rgb(255, 255 - (int) i, 0);  
  index++;  
 }  
 return Color.RED;  
 }  

 // Update the main field colors depending on the current selected hue  
 private void updateMainColors() {  
  int mainColor = getCurrentMainColor();  
  int index = 0;  
  int[] topColors = new int[256];  
  for (int y = 0; y < 256; y++) {  
  for (int x = 0; x < 256; x++) {  
   if (y == 0) {  
   mMainColors[index] = Color.rgb(  
    255 - (255 - Color.red(mainColor)) * x / 255,  
    255 - (255 - Color.green(mainColor)) * x / 255,  
    255 - (255 - Color.blue(mainColor)) * x / 255);  
   topColors[x] = mMainColors[index];  
  } else  
   mMainColors[index] = Color.rgb(  
    (255 - y) * Color.red(topColors[x]) / 255,  
    (255 - y) * Color.green(topColors[x]) / 255,  
    (255 - y) * Color.blue(topColors[x]) / 255);  
  index++;  
  }  
  }  
 }  

 @Override  
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {  
 int translatedHue = 255 - (int) (mCurrentHue * 255 / 360);  
 // Display all the colors of the hue bar with lines  
  for (int x = 0; x < 256; x++) {  
 // If this is not the current selected hue, display the actual  
 // color  
  if (translatedHue != x) {  
   mPaint.setColor(mHueBarColors[x]);  
   mPaint.setStrokeWidth(1);  
   } else // else display a slightly larger black line  
  {  
 mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);  
 mPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);  
  }  
  canvas.drawLine(x + 10, 0, x + 10, 40, mPaint);  
 // canvas.drawLine(0, x+10, 40, x+10, mPaint);  
  }  

  // Display the main field colors using LinearGradient  
  for (int x = 0; x < 256; x++) {  
  int[] colors = new int[2];  
  colors[0] = mMainColors[x];  
  colors[1] = Color.BLACK;  
   Shader shader = new LinearGradient(0, 50, 0, 306, colors, null, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);  
   mPaint.setShader(shader);  
   canvas.drawLine(x + 10, 50, x + 10, 306, mPaint);  
   }  
  mPaint.setShader(null);  

 // Display the circle around the currently selected color in the  
 // main field  
 if (mCurrentX != 0 && mCurrentY != 0) {  
  mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);  
  mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);  
  canvas.drawCircle(mCurrentX, mCurrentY, 10, mPaint);  
  }  

  // Draw a 'button' with the currently selected color  
  mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);  
  mPaint.setColor(mCurrentColor);  
  canvas.drawRect(10, 316, 138, 356, mPaint);  

 // Set the text color according to the brightness of the color  
 if (Color.red(mCurrentColor) + Color.green(mCurrentColor) + Color.blue(mCurrentColor) < 384)  
  mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);  
  else  
  mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);  
  canvas.drawText("Pick", 74, 340, mPaint);  



  // Draw a 'button' with the default color  
  mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);  
  mPaint.setColor(mDefaultColor);  
  canvas.drawRect(138, 316, 266, 356, mPaint);  

  // Set the text color according to the brightness of the color  
  if (Color.red(mDefaultColor) + Color.green(mDefaultColor)  
   + Color.blue(mDefaultColor) < 384)  
   mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);  
  else  
  mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);  
  canvas.drawText("Cancel", 202, 340,  
  mPaint);  
 }  

 private void startActivity(Intent a) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  button1.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);


}

private Context getApplicationContext() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return null;
}

 @Override  
 protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {  
  setMeasuredDimension(276, 366);  
  }  

 @Override  
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {  
 if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)  
  return true;  
  float x = event.getX();  
  float y = event.getY();  

  // If the touch event is located in the hue bar  
  if (x > 10 && x < 266 && y > 0 && y < 40) {  
  // Update the main field colors  
  mCurrentHue = (255 - x) * 360 / 255;  
  updateMainColors();  

  // Update the current selected color  
  int transX = mCurrentX - 10;  
  int transY = mCurrentY - 60;  
  int index = 256 * (transY - 1) + transX;  
  if (index > 0 && index < mMainColors.length)  
 mCurrentColor = mMainColors[256 * (transY - 1) + transX];  

  // Force the redraw of the dialog  
  invalidate();  
  }  

   // If the touch event is located in the main field  
  if (x > 10 && x < 266 && y > 50 && y < 306) {  
  mCurrentX = (int) x;  
  mCurrentY = (int) y;  
  int transX = mCurrentX - 10;  
  int transY = mCurrentY - 60;  
  int index = 256 * (transY - 1) + transX;  
  if (index > 0 && index < mMainColors.length) {  
   // Update the current color  
   mCurrentColor = mMainColors[index];  
   // Force the redraw of the dialog  
  invalidate();  
  }  
 }  

 // If the touch event is located in the left button, notify the  
 // listener with the current color  
 if (x > 10 && x < 138 && y > 316 && y < 356)  
  mListener.colorChanged("", mCurrentColor);  

 // If the touch event is located in the right button, notify the  
 // listener with the default color  
  if (x > 138 && x < 266 && y > 316 && y < 356)  
  mListener.colorChanged("", mDefaultColor);  

 return true;  
 }  
 }  

 public ColorPicker(Context context, OnColorChangedListener listener,  
 String key, int initialColor, int defaultColor) {  
 super(context);  

 mListener = listener;  
 mKey = key;  
 mInitialColor = initialColor;  
 mDefaultColor = defaultColor;  
 }  

@Override  
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
OnColorChangedListener l = new OnColorChangedListener() {  
 public void colorChanged(String key, int color) {  
 mListener.colorChanged(mKey, color);  
 dismiss();  
 }  
 };  

 setContentView(new ColorPickerView(getContext(), l, mInitialColor,  
 mDefaultColor));  
 setTitle("Pick a color");  

}  
}
```

If anybody knows about this then plz help me.
   NOTE:I only need color picker dialog once when the app is run for the first time after    installation.

Comment: Make your colour picker the MAIN/LAUNCHER `Activity` and follow the approach of the answer to the question I've linked to. Basically, check `SharedPreferences` for a `boolean` - if it is a 'first run' scenario then do what you need to do then start the 'main' `Activity` - if it's not a 'first run' then start your 'main' `Activity` directly and call `finish()` on your colour picker `Activity`.